# Security Exception when loading the site after Kentico upgrade from v9 to v10

Tags: upgrade, kentico

After upgrading the existing v9 site to Kentico 10 I'm getting a security exception error when loading the site. The CMS admin however loads fine. I already added the FULL trust setting in web.config but it did not work. Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem, based on part that I can see and exception type would be in new SQL parser which was added in one of the hotfixes for v9 and thus it is part of v10.

You seem to be using one of the properties in a web part and than passing incomplete query via ##WHERE## macro. If a where condition is like {%CurrentDocument.DocumentID%} it is not a valid WHERE and whole property has to be complete SQL statement on its own, so it could be like DocumentID = {%CurrentDocument.DocumentID%}.

You can find a bit more in this thread:

https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/invalid-sql-query-error-on-a-page

Comment: "WHERE" text is not allowed anymore inside the where condition text field. It has to be included in the custom query before the "##WHERE##" expression. e.g. select * from custom_table WHERE ##WHERE##

Answer (score 1):

Try load the template in the Admin UI pages application, then check the event log application, you should see the detail information about the SQL error. Most likely you have a SQL call that is trying to get some data from a column that's no longer there (through upgrade).

Comment: Thanks, checking the event logs helped me see other errors in our custom webparts like missing CMS assemblies due to the upgrade.